# How to hide port number 8443 from the URL - tomcat 8.5

Tags: tomcat8

I need to hide the tomcat8.5 port number from the URL.
Currently having https://localhost:8443/Jasperserver-pro

I need https://localhost/Jasperserver-pro.

Could you please provide me the complete step by step procedure.

Environment :

RHEL7. 6 Linux azure cloud instance

SSL enabled environment.

Thanks in advance, 
Maduraipandian Manivel.

Answer (score 0):

The URL scheme "https://" implies port 443 by default. If you want to use a different port number, such as 8443, that port number must be in the URL; web browsers will not let you hide it. To remove the port number from the URL, you must run the server on port 443.

Comment: Is it enough if I change connector port to 443.